# Configuring subdomain document root Apache

Tags: node.js, apache

I have an Apache web server with mysite.com and img.mysite.com.

I made a conf file since it is a nodejs app, so I could point passenger to the right locations.
I have 2 folders, /home/user/img, and /home/user/mysite.

I have a conf file located at my web servers includes file location

In the conf file I have

```
DocumentRoot /home/user/mysite
# Use server.js as the startup file (entry point file) for
# your Node.js application, instead of the default app.js
PassengerStartupFile server.js
PassengerAppType node
PassengerAppRoot /home/user/mysite
```

The problem I'm having is that the subdomain points to wherever the DocumentRoot is, So if I have the DocumentRoot at /home/user/mysite, going to img.mysite.com will just show the file directory for the main project. What is curious is if I do this,

```
DocumentRoot /home/user/img
# Use server.js as the startup file (entry point file) for
# your Node.js application, instead of the default app.js
PassengerStartupFile server.js
PassengerAppType node
PassengerAppRoot /home/user/mysite
```

This works, but if someone ever goes to img.mysite.com, they can just see the entire file directory for the subdomain, it wont throw a 443 error. Also, if I create a little index.html file so that they can't see the directory, the main domain points to it as well, so going to img.mysite.com points to the index.html within /home/user/img/index.html, and so does the main domain! Is there any way to configure it so that the DocumentRoot for the main domain is different than the subdomain?

Comment: DocumentRoot was setting the document root for both for some reason. By Removing the DocumentRoot line, the VirtualHost configuration in httpd.conf remained, and corrected itself